What is the sample mean in Central limit theorem?
Lindeberg–Lévy CLT
Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3 … X_n$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$.
Then, as $n$ approaches infinity, the sample mean:
$$ \overline{X} = \dfrac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{n} $$
converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$

My question is:
How to calculate the sample mean? Does it require there are the same amount of numbers $x$ in $X_i$?
for example:
$$ X_1 = [0, 1, 2],  X_2 = [0.5, 1, 1.5]$$
Is sample mean $X_\text{bar}[i] = (X_1[i] + X_2[i])/2 = [0.25, 1, 1.75]$?
What about $X_1 = [0, 1, 2], X_2 = [-1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 3]$

Each sample point must draw from the same sample space, that is, each sample point must at least have the same dimension. Your last example, $$ X_1=[0,1,2], X_2=[−1,0.5,1,1.5,3] $$ doesn't make sense, as $X_1$ is from $\mathbb{R}^3$ but $X_2$ is from $\mathbb{R}^5$

So that you mean it is necessary to have the same amount of number in each $X_i$?

Is there any problem with $\overline{X}[i] = (1/n) \sum_{k=1}^n X_k[i]$

You wrote a scalar version central limit theorem.  Since the distribution converges to a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\sigma^2/n$, each sample is a scalar.  Of course, you could formulate this in terms of vectors.  As pointed out in the comments, each vector would need to be of the same dimension, otherwise the sum is not defined.  And yes, add up the samples and then divide by the number of samples.
